# How to skip the first row when reading a csv file?

Tags: go

I have an awkward csv file and I need to skip the first row to read it.

I'm doing this easily with python/pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1)
```

but I don't know how to do it in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type mwericsson struct {
    id     string
    name   string
    region string
}

func main() {

    rows := readSample()

    fmt.Println(rows)
    //appendSum(rows)
    //writeChanges(rows)
}

func readSample() [][]string {
    f, err := os.Open("D:/in/20190629/PM_IG30014_15_201906290015_01.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rows, err := csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return rows
}
```

Error:

```
2019/07/01 12:38:40 record on line 2: wrong number of fields
```

`PM_IG30014_15_201906290015_01.csv`:

```
PTN Ethernet-Port RMON Performance,PORT_BW_UTILIZATION,2019-06-29 20:00:00,33366     
DeviceID,DeviceName,ResourceName,CollectionTime,GranularityPeriod,PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION,PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION,RXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED,TXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED,PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX,PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX
3174659,H1095,H1095-11-ISM6-1(to ZJBSC-V1),2019-06-29 20:00:00,15,22.08,4.59,,,30.13,6.98
3174659,H1095,H1095-14-ISM6-1(to T6147-V),2019-06-29 20:00:00,15,2.11,10.92,,,4.43,22.45
```

Comment: You can even stop checking for same number of fields by setting FieldsPerRecord to negative value : https://play.golang.org/p/uFmRpYIbskX.       After ignoring FieldPerRecord Your csv will parsed successfully, you can then just skip row one in your for loop

Comment: @mchampaneri: Removing an error check is not a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> skip the first row when reading a csv file

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func readSample(rs io.ReadSeeker) ([][]string, error) {
    // Skip first row (line)
    row1, err := bufio.NewReader(rs).ReadSlice('\n')
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = rs.Seek(int64(len(row1)), io.SeekStart)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Read remaining rows
    r := csv.NewReader(rs)
    rows, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return rows, nil
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("sample.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    rows, err := readSample(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(rows)
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat sample.csv
one,two,three,four
1,2,3
4,5,6
$ go run sample.go
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
$ 

$ cat sample.csv
PTN Ethernet-Port RMON Performance,PORT_BW_UTILIZATION,2019-06-29 20:00:00,33366     
DeviceID,DeviceName,ResourceName,CollectionTime,GranularityPeriod,PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION,PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION,RXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED,TXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED,PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX,PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX
3174659,H1095,H1095-11-ISM6-1(to ZJBSC-V1),2019-06-29 20:00:00,15,22.08,4.59,,,30.13,6.98
3174659,H1095,H1095-14-ISM6-1(to T6147-V),2019-06-29 20:00:00,15,2.11,10.92,,,4.43,22.45
$ go run sample.go
[[DeviceID DeviceName ResourceName CollectionTime GranularityPeriod PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION RXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED TXGOODFULLFRAMESPEED PORT_RX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX PORT_TX_BW_UTILIZATION_MAX] [3174659 H1095 H1095-11-ISM6-1(to ZJBSC-V1) 2019-06-29 20:00:00 15 22.08 4.59   30.13 6.98] [3174659 H1095 H1095-14-ISM6-1(to T6147-V) 2019-06-29 20:00:00 15 2.11 10.92   4.43 22.45]]
$
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply call [`Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader.Read) to read a line, then proceed to read the rest with [`Reader.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader.ReadAll).

See this example:

```
src := "one,two,three\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"

r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(src))
if _, err := r.Read(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

records, err := r.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(records)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UgAA3VyEKP-)):

```
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```

Comment: It's not working for my csv file, I just want to skip first row when I'm reading csv file.
by this way it is giving me empty []

Comment: @MortezaHasanabadi As you can see, I provided a working example where it _does_ work. If it doesn't work for you, you should post the code you tried and a minimal example input it doesn't  work with for you but it should.

Comment: I tried my csv file with the code that you provided.
can you please try your code with my file?

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8365291018/PM_IG30014_15_201906292000_01.csv.html

Comment: Just post the first few lines of your file in the question. Also post what errors you get if any.

Comment: @icza: In the question, the error was "record on line 2: wrong number of fields.". For example, `src := "one,two,three,four\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"`.: https://play.golang.org/p/9RqHUVwbkJP. See my answer.

Comment: @peterSO use `r.FieldsPerRecord = -1` if you do not have the same number of fields in rows: https://play.golang.org/p/KT8qOzjdnyY

Comment: @ffox003: `FieldsPerRecord = -1` bypasses the check that all but the first record have the same number of fields. Bypassing error checks is not a good idea.

Comment: @peterSO then why not just disabling it for the first line?
https://play.golang.org/p/Pdx-z1LM83Y

Answer (score 1):

while it was informative to learn about io.ReadSeeker, I think a simpler way to skip the first line/row (often times the header) of a csv is to use the slice functionality as follows:

```
func readCsv(filename string) [][]string {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    records := [][]string{}
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        records = append(records, record)
    }
    return records[1:] // skip the header
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can just use `bufio.ReadBytes('\n')` and pass bufio as Reader to csv.NewReader

```golang
func readSample(reader io.Reader) ([][]string, error) {
    // if reader is bufio, we don't need to NewReader againg
    buf, ok := (reader).(*bufio.Reader)
    if !ok {
        buf = bufio.NewReader(reader)
    }
    _, err := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    rows, err := csv.NewReader(buf).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return rows, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ReadAll reads all the remaining records from r. Each record is a slice of fields. A successful call `returns err == nil`, not `err == io.EOF`. Because `ReadAll` is defined to read until `EOF`, it does not treat the end of the file as an error to be reported.

- https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Reader.ReadAll

So, you could:

```golang
    r := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(content))
    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for key, value := range records {
        // Skip the first line
        if key == 0 {
            continue
        }
        // Process your data here.
        ...
    }
```